# Should I do anything about a user posting their mobile number on their About Me?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

I recently visited a user's profile page and noticed that they have posted their mobile number on the "About Me" section. In my opinion, this isn't the kind of personal information that should be shared and the user should be encouraged to remove it.

Does this even need bringing to anybody's attention? Should the user be encouraged to remove it?  While it **is** personal information, the user has volunteered the information and should potentially be allowed to do so.

If this should be actioned, how, and to whom should I report this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what? This is their number, and it's their full right to post it wherever they want.

If you really want, you can leave a comment on one of their posts, if there is any post, saying their mobile number is public for everyone, or if the user have 20+ reputation invite to chat and say it there, which is better and less noisy.

All in all, no need to flag and no need to worry, unless you have reason to believe it's not their own number (i.e. they harass someone else by publishing their number), in which case it should be removed indeed.

Comment: Thanks. I was on the fence between "So what?" and "Should this kind of information be removed?" Doesn't stop me from thinking that it's foolish and *should* be removed, but I'm happy to do nothing more.

Answer (score 5):

> this isn't the kind of personal information that should be shared

Why not? Wouldn't that be a personal thing if you want to share your phone number, home address, gender, sexual preference, etc? If you don't want to share it, it is your right to keep it that way.

> Should the user be encouraged to remove it?

Well, users *can* be unaware of the implications of sharing their phone number on the internet. We have to assume they know. There is nothing for us to do.

You can ping the user in chat, but what for? What will it help? The phone number is already there and has probably been picked up by search engines already. Flagging to let moderators remove it won't be a good idea either. It is not their decision to remove such personal information if a user wants to share it.